# Running GWT SuperDevMode in IDEA on Win8

Tags: gwt, windows-8, intellij-idea, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am trying to configure my GWT project to run in SuperDevMode and experience severe problem during server run time.

So, I have working "regular" devMode configuration in Intellij IDEA. Created a new GWT configuration in app-servers list. Set the following values:

[Checked] Super Dev Mode

**VM options**: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384M

**Dev Mode parameters**: -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 -port 1234 -workDir d:\projects\myApp\SDV\ -src d:\projects\myApp\src\main\java com.app.MyApp

Made changes to my project's build xml file adding the lines in the end of file:

```
    <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
    <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
    <!-- enable source maps -->
    <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

Here is the console output on this config run:

```
workDir: d:\projects\myApp\SDV
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
binding: user.agent=safari
binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
binding: locale=en
Compiling module com.app.MyApp
   Compiling 1 permutation
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Source Maps Enabled
   Compile of permutations succeeded
Linking into d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1\war\myapp; Writing extras to d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1\extras\myapp
   Link succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 84.458s
Compile completed in 85210 ms
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
[ERROR] unable to create directory: d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CompileDir.mkdir(CompileDir.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CompileDir.create(CompileDir.java:93)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.makeCompileDir(Recompiler.java:267)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:82)
    ....
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I suspect it maybe Win8 file access permissions problem: cannot create the directory because it wasn't deleted successfully. Both lines in the log above that have this text:

```
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
```

are of red color in IDEA (if that has any special meaning).

I unchecked READ_ONLY checkbox in the properties of for the work folder in file explorer, and also run idea64.exe as Admin. Should I somehow run this codeserver compiler "as admin" too? Is it possible?

Also it may be a configuration issue, if it is and somebody can see it from the details below - I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Running the superDevMode config with parameter "-noprecompile" gives the same results:

```
workDir: d:\projects\myApp\sdv
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\sdv\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
Module setup completed in 865 ms
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\sdv\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
[ERROR] unable to create directory: d:\projects\myApp\sdv\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CompileDir.mkdir(CompileDir.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CompileDir.create(CompileDir.java:93)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.makeCompileDir(Recompiler.java:267)
```

So, definitely looks like file access problem (*delete* doesn't do its job?). Javadoc to `CompileDir.create()` method says: "`Creates a new compileDir directory structure. The directory must not already exist, but its parent should exist.`" Seems that it already exists.

Comment: Is this on every compile, or does it happen after a while?

Your temp drive may simply be full.

Comment: I can't compile even once. So it's a real showstopper for me. Lots of space on the drive.

Comment: I created a GWT issue to track this: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8619

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will follow it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is fixed now in GWT 2.7.0 by GWT team.
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8619

Runs well, even though I can notice the message in the IDE console:

> [WARN] unable to delete 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-1341369077945982663.tmp\com.bla.MyAPP\compile-1' (skipped)
>    [ERROR] unable to create directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-1341369077945982663.tmp\com.bla.MyAPP\compile-1
>   Loading Java files in com.bla.MyAPP.

after printing this the IDE continues to run the app server.

Resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your configuration is correct. I am using the same parameters (with another portnumber) on my Mac and it works as expected.

The red color of the text:

```
deleting: d:\projects\myApp\SDV\com.app.MyApp\compile-1
```

is normal and indicates no problem.

I am not familiar with Windows 8, but would think, that you don't need to run idea.exe with admin rights. I think, uncheck the read-only checkbox should solve your problems.

Another way should be, that you create your workDir directory with Intellij.

File -> New -> directory

(That's what I did).

Comment: > "create your workDir directory with Intellij." 

Didn't help. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that if you are converting your project from GWT 2.6.0 to 2.7.0, you should delete your 2.6.0 run configuration and setup a new one with GWT 2.7.0 defaults.